# How to refer inner enum in JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have an Enum inside a class, that stores its entity's value in database, and I want to refer to this column to make query. Here's entities:

```
public class PostBox{
    private Message message;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

public class Message{

    private Answer answer;

    @Column(name = "ANSWER")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Answer getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static enum Answer{
        MAYBE_YES,
        MAYBE_NO,
        MAYBE_I_DONT_KNOW

        @Getter
        private final String label;
    }
}
```

What I want to achive in simple english: `Select * from POSTBOX where MESSAGE IN (SELECT * from MESSAGE where ANSWER = MAYBE_NO)`

Here's what I came with

```
@Override
public final Specification<PostBox> byFilter(final PostBoxFilter filter) {
    return new Specification<PostBox>() {  
        @Override    
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<PostBox> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            return builder.equal(root.join(PostBox_.message).get(Message_.answer), filter.getAnswer());
        }
    };
}
```

But it gives `error : no suitable method found for get(SingularAttribute<Message,Answer>)`

How should I access this variable?

Comment: Your query should be actually as simple as `final Predicate answerPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("answer"), filter.getAnswer());`